# why is the hash function at the level not working?

Tags: php, laravel, hash

I try to make hash password in my controller, but i getting error like
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::updateOrCreate(): Argument #2 ($values) must be of type array, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\production\namasindo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php on line 23

This is my controller

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data=$request->All();
        $data= Hash::make($request->password);
        User::updateOrCreate(["id"=>$request->id], $data);
        return response()->json($data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting your `$data` with the hash.

See:

```php
    $data= Hash::make($request->password);
```

You mean to do:

```
    $data['password'] = Hash::make($request->password);
```

Answer (score 0):

2nd Argument is an array so here $data must be an array

```
$data['password'] = Hash::make($request->password);
```